# Creating my own authored repository for Test-First-Ruby solutions

Tags: git, github

I want to create my own origin git for the solutions of Test First Ruby by Alex Chaffee.

How exactly can I do that?

I wish to create the repo in which I am the author and I realize that I need to repeat the entire history for that.

I assume that there's a way to somehow copy Alex's original repository with the problems and then work on it?

Some people have done that, but I cannot find a way to do so myself.

Comment: I sense that what you need is [making a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo).

Answer (score 1):

Fork the repository; you can then contribute to your own version of the project.

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Comment: If i fork it, i wont be its author would i?

Comment: the author and the origin would remain the same

Comment: @aayushgx, commits have authors, repositories only have origins. You will be the author of the commits you make.